# Problem with creating own module Block with an SQL query

Tags: 7, blocks, database, userpoints

I’m trying to create a custom module that implements a block to display something I haven’t been able to do with the Views 2 module.
I’ve tried to look at some guides and tutorials, but I haven’t got any result yet.

I can print out the first SELECT attribute in the first row. The first row make sense since I don’t loop through it but still I’m confused on how to do the rest.

```
function sn_most_contributed_block($op='list', $delta=0) {
  if ($op == "list") {
    // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page
    $block = array();
    $block[0]["info"] = t('Most Contribution this week (custom module');
    return $block;
  } 
  elseif ($op == 'view') {    
    $mce = db_result(
      db_query("SELECT node.uid, COUNT(nid), users.picture AS users_picture, users.uid AS users_uid, users.name AS users_name, users.mail AS users_mail FROM node node INNER JOIN users users ON node.uid = users.uid WHERE (node.type IN ('leads',  'qa',  'qa_comments',  'til_salg',  'tips_tricks')) AND node.created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) AND node.created <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL 1 DAY ) GROUP BY uid ORDER BY COUNT(nid) DESC LIMIT 0 , 5")
    );

    $block_content .= "Most contributed members are: " . $mce';
    $block_content .= "<div class='author picture profile_image'>In here should be the user image</div>";
    $block_content .= "<div id='username'>In here should be the username</div>";

    if ($block_content == '') {   
      $block['subject'] = 'contribution test';
      $block['content'] = 'yay';
      return $block;
    }
    else {
      // set up the block  
      $block = array();
      $block['subject'] = 'Most contribution this week';  
      $block['content'] = $block_content;
      return $block;
    }
  }
}

I’ve tested my query in the database environment for my Drupal site and it works and print everything it should out correctly.

For looping the query, I tried this code with no result.

while ($contriUser = db_fetch_object($mce)) {
  $contriUser [] = $contriUser->uid;
}

I have also tried the following code.

while ($contriUser = db_fetch_object($mce)) {
  var_dump($contriUser);
}
```

Any help on how to solve this or if someone has an alternative solution to get the most contributing members last seven days it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, there is a syntax error inside `"Most contributed members are: " . $mce';`. The `'` at the end is wrong. But I think that's not the actual problem.

Comment: Is the block even being created at all?  You seem to be using the Drupal 6 version of hook_block but the post is tagged 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most contributing members you may want to look at the [user points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) [modules](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib), they give you a lot of very nice features.

A couple of quick pointers with your code as you are asking.

Your query should use parameters and be formatted according to drupal [coding standards](http://drupal.org/node/2497), this helps for security and portability. The coder module can help you with this.

To get the results you will probably want something like [db_fetch_array](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_fetch_array/6) in a loop

```
 $result_set = db_query("SELECT ...");
 while ($result = db_fetch_array($result_set)) {
   $block_content .= ...;
 }
```

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: To further add, `db_result()` should be used when the query is returning a single field, such as `SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE …`. If you need to get only a result but the query is not selecting a single field, then you should use `db_query_range()`.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to the interesting part. Check out this untested code:

```
$block_content = "";
$result_set = db_query("SELECT node.uid, 
  COUNT(nid), 
  users.picture AS users_picture, 
  users.uid AS users_uid, 
  users.name AS users_name, 
  users.mail AS users_mail 
  FROM {node} 
  INNER JOIN {users} ON node.uid = users.uid 
  WHERE (node.type IN ('leads',  'qa',  'qa_comments',  'til_salg',  'tips_tricks')) 
  AND node.created >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 1 WEEK ) 
  AND node.created <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL 1 DAY ) 
  GROUP BY uid 
  ORDER BY COUNT( nid ) DESC 
  LIMIT 0 , 5"
);

$block_content .= t("Most contributed members are: ");
while ($result = db_fetch_array($result_set)) {
  $block_content .= '<div class="author picture profile_image"><img src="'.$result['users_picture'].'"/></div>';      
  $block_content .= '<div id="username">'.$result['users_name'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: [db_query_range()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_query_range/6) should be used when you want to limit the number of returned table rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have views 3, dereine has kindly posted an import for this http://drupal.org/node/1186598#comment-4593972